# Python garbage collection giving me a hard time

Tags: python, web-applications, google-app-engine, garbage-collection

**Context:** I am developing a web application using `webapp2` web-framework with python to be hosted on GAE. 
The web application (*web-app* from now on), is a chess variant. Being a first timer, I have definitely made a lot of design blunders. One of them, is what this question is regarding to, I will come to it in a short while.

The aim of the web-app was to allow quite a large number of players to play 2-player chess, such that multiple games are running in parallel. While not exceeding the free quota on GAE. (*I am a student*).

To do that, I thought that I would create a new game object, and store its `id(game_object)` along with the `machine_id` of the two players playing on that instance, in the datastore.

When querying the datastore with the `machine_id` of a player, I could get a `id()` value, and I thought could use that value as a `key` in a dictionary wherein a reference to the `game_object` forms the value.

Doing this, doesn't need me to write/update the datastore, hence saving on the precious writes. I could easily modify the game-state of the `game_object`, and it could be still referenced by the `id()`.

**But, now what happens is, this works fine for a few moves. After that the garbage collection takes place and the `game_object` is wiped off the memory. Raising a NameError exception.**

**My question is, can this be solved by creating new game_objects in a separate module where garbage collection is turned off, and then periodically/event-triggered freeing the memory? If not? How do I come around this problem?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not running into the Python garbage collection process here. Google App Engine doesn't guarantee that all requests go to the same instance. **New** instances do not share memory with old instances.

Load your data into memory again when your dictionary is empty.

All that the CPython garbage collector does is break circular references so that the normal reference count mechanism can remove objects from memory when no longer used. Your process has a dictionary referring to your data, and the garbage collector would *never* touch that data.

Comment: The web-app is still in development and is being hosted on the local machine. `Google App Engine doesn't guarantee that all requests go to the same instance.` Will that be an issue even on the local machine?

Comment: The local dev server supports multiple backend instances, so yes.

Comment: Aah! Ok. So is there no other way, than to store the game-state in the datastore in some or the other representation.

Comment: You can still cache stuff locally, or you could use the new MemCached implementation now available on GAE.

Comment: Is it safe to assume that the python garbage collector does *not* touch *any* python dictionary data-type?

Comment: If the only reference to the dictionary object is part of a circular reference the garbage collector *will* touch it to break the circle.

Comment: Outside of circular references the GC won't be involved. CPython instead relies on reference counting. If you still have a reference to an object it'll remain alive indefinitely.